# MVC - Count in a foreach loop, best practice

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foreach

I have been working on getting a count records within a foreach loop.  I am going to need run many of these counts on a single page.  I am looking for the most efficient way to do this.

I have gotten this far, but I am not sure if I headed down the right path.  If I am, how do I get this data into my view.

ViewModel

```
public class AgtLeadStatsListVM
{
    public string LoanAgent { get; set; }
    public DateTime LeadDate { get; set; }
    public int LeadDailyCt { get; set; }
    public int LeadWeeklyCt { get; set; }
    public int LeadMTDCt { get; set; }
    public int LeadYTDCt { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MWFUser> AgentList { get; set; }
    public virtual WebLead Lead { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
 var model = new AgtLeadStatsListVM();            
 {
 // Get Selected Agent's Information
 var AgentList = from l in db.MWFUsers
                 where (l.UserTitle == "Banker"
                 select l;

    foreach (var agent in AgentList)
    {

    // Daily Lead Count
    var LeadDailyCt = db.WebLeads.Count(x => (x.LoanAgent == agent.UserEmail)
    && (x.LeadDate >= todayDate && x.LeadDate <= todayEndDay));

    // Weekly Lead Count
    var LeadWeeklyCt = db.WebLeads.Count(x => (x.LoanAgent == agent.UserEmail)
                                         && x.LeadDate >= firstOfWeek
                                         && x.LeadDate <= todayEndDay);

    // Monthly Lead Count
    var LeadMTDCount = db.WebLeads.Count(x => (x.LoanAgent == agent.UserEmail)
                                         && x.LeadDate >= firstOfMonth
                                         && x.LeadDate <= todayEndDay);

   // YTD Lead Count
   var LeadYTDCount = db.WebLeads.Count(x => (x.LoanAgent == agent.UserEmail)
                                         && x.LeadDate >= firstOfMonth
                                         && x.LeadDate <= todayEndDay);
}
}
```

View

```
@model LoanModule.ViewModels.AgtLeadStatsListVM

<div>
    @foreach (var item in Model.AgentList)
    {
    <p>@Model.LoanAgent</p>
    <p>@Model.LeadDailyCt</p>
    <p>@Model.LeadWeeklyCt</p>
    <p>@Model.LeadMTDCt</p>
    <p>@Model.LeadYTDCt</p>
    }
```

I am receiving this error on my View: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  (on line: @foreach (var item in Model.AgentList))

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: For "better practices" I would create a function of `IEnumerable<AgtLeadStatsListVM> BuildAgentList(string title)` and properly implement it. This will make it fairly easy to see what the main 'disconnect' problem is when doing `var model = new AgtLeadStatsListVM();  model.AgentList =  BuildAgentList("Banker");`. The NPE is looks as a result of not understanding how C# properties are set.

Comment: Also, the multiplicities for the subsequent properties are are all wrong - these should probably be part of the each resulting 'Agent' object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semicolon at the end of `var model = new AgtLeadStatsListVM();` means that you are no longer in an object initializer after that line. The syntax you're probably trying for is something more along these lines:

```
var agents = 
    from l in db.MWFUsers
    where l.UserTitle == "Banker"
    select l;

var model = new AgtLeadStatsListVM
{
    // Get Selected Agent's Information
    AgentList = agents.ToList(),
    // Daily Lead Count
    LeadDailyCt = agents.Sum(a => db.WebLeads.Count(
        x => (x.LoanAgent == a.UserEmail)
            && (x.LeadDate >= todayDate && x.LeadDate <= todayEndDay)))
    // ...
}
```

By the way, if you want to get all of this information in a single round-trip, you could use this `group by`-based trick.

```
var model = 
    (from agent in agents
    let webLeads = db.WebLeads.Where(x => x.LoanAgent == agent.UserEmail)
    group new{agent, webLeads} by 0 into g
    select new AgtLeadStatsListVM
    {
        // Get Selected Agent's Information
        AgentList = g.Select(e => e.agent).ToList(),
        // Daily Lead Count
        LeadDailyCt = g.Sum(e => e.webLeads.Count(x => x.LeadDate >= todayDate && x.LeadDate <= todayEndDay)),
        // ...
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

### Update

From your comments it sounds like this is more what you're going for:

```
var model = 
    (from agent in agents
    let webLeads = db.WebLeads.Where(x => x.LoanAgent == agent.UserEmail)
    select new AgtLeadStatsListVM
    {
        // Get Selected Agent's Information
        LoanAgent = agent.UserEmail,
        // Daily Lead Count
        LeadDailyCt = webLeads.Count(x => x.LeadDate >= todayDate && x.LeadDate <= todayEndDay),
        // ...
    }).ToList();
```

And your view code:

```
@model IEnumerable<LoanModule.ViewModels.AgtLeadStatsListVM>

<div>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
      <p>@item.LoanAgent</p>
      <p>@item.LeadDailyCt</p>
      <p>@item.LeadWeeklyCt</p>
      <p>@item.LeadMTDCt</p>
      <p>@item.LeadYTDCt</p>
    }
```

The `AgentList` property should be removed from your model entirely.

Comment: Thank you.  I almost have this working!  The foreach loop for the agent in the view is returning the total sum for all agents, not just that particular agent.  I tried to remove the sum at the beginning of the statement, but then how do I reference the list of agents?

 agents.Sum(a => db.WebLeads.Count(
        x => (x.LoanAgent == a.UserEmail)
            && (x.LeadDate >= todayDate && x.LeadDate <= todayEndDay)))e

Comment: @Daniela: When you say "that particular agent", how are you identifying that agent? Is `UserTitle = "Banker"` enough to restrict your results to the agent you're looking for? (By the way, I strongly recommend using numeric ID values for your primary and foreign keys. Querying by a magic-string `UserTitle` and joining tables on `LoanAgent == UserEmail` is probably not a great idea.)

Comment: It is by x.LoanAgent == a.UserEmail.   The way this project evolved, the foreign key wasn't necessary at first (the agent was just an email address tied to nothing).  So for agent, John Doe, I am looking for how many leads he has been assigned to in a day, week, month and year.  I am looking for that number for each agent in the list.  Thank for your help...learning as I go here.

Comment: @Daniela: If you want to have those numbers for each agent in the list, then you need to redesign your Vm class: right now it has the AgentList as one property, and the numbers as other properties. I'm guessing you want your model to be a list of objects that each has an agent name and the counts.

Comment: @Daniela: See my edit. When you're trying to grab data for a bunch of different objects in the database, you definitely don't want to do it in a `for` loop, because that will cause as many round-trips to the database as you have items in your list. Instead, construct a query that will give you all of the data you're looking for in one round-trip

Comment: It worked with this slight adjustment:  
 LeadDailyCt = webLeads.Count(x => x.LeadDate >= todayDate && x.LeadDate <= todayEndDay && x.LoanAgent == agent.UserEmail)

I have got a lot to learn still..... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I am receiving this error on my View: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. (on line: @foreach (var item in
>   Model.AgentList))

The `AgentList` is null.

Furthermore, you haven't initialized correctly your model.

Specifically, this line of code

```
var model = new AgtLeadStatsListVM();
```

creates a new object of type `AgtLeadStatsListVM`, where

- `LoanAgent` is null
- `LeadDate` 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
- `LeadDailyCt` is 0
- `LeadWeeklyCt` is 0
- `LeadMTDCt` is 0
- `LeadYTDCt` is 0
- `AgentList` is null
- `WebLead` is Lead

The default values, since you didn't set any value. Probably, you want to make use of an object initializer, there you don't need `();`. We write just this:

```
var model = new AgtLeadStatsListVM
{
    LoadAgent = "Name of the LoadAgent",
    LeadDate = DateTime.Now.Utc,
    LeadDailyCt = agents.Sum(a => db.WebLeads.Count(
    x => (x.LoanAgent == a.UserEmail)
        && (x.LeadDate >= todayDate && x.LeadDate <= todayEndDay)))
    // Do the same for the rest of the corresponding properties.
}
```

Comment: Correct! No where in the code you provided was it set.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to ignore the error that you are getting (see other answers for it) and reference only *best practice and a most efficient way for counting* part of the question.

The most efficient way (at least in my opinion) would be using some caching technique for the result and updating the cache on daily basis(since the maximum resolution that you use is daily). Clearly, choosing an appropriate caching mechanism depends on your application. It can go from storing some data in static variable on application start, to running a dedicated [Redis server](http://redis.io/topics/lru-cache) (or any other fast data structure store). The bottom line here is: try to minimize the number of queries to DB and cache any suitable data.

Comment: Once I get my queries working, I will look into that.  This is a small n MVC 5 app with less than internal 20 users.  Do you know of any tutorials that might be helpful?

Comment: This could be a nice blog to start with: http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/net4-caching-with-mvc/